# UICollectionView Scrolling to an Item

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to memorize an index for an item (indexPath.item) in a UICollectionView and at a later time, after the view is replaced and then restored, to scroll to that memorized item.

When memorizing the item, indexPath, and indexPath.item are:

```
indexPath is: <NSIndexPath 0x1d87b380> 2 indexes [0, 32]
indexPath.item is: 32
```

When recalculating the indexPath later for that item, indexPath, and indexPath.item are:

```
indexPath is: <NSIndexPath 0x1d8877b0> 2 indexes [0, 32]
item is: 32
```

I try to scroll to the memorized location by using:

```
NSIndexPath *iPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
[self collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:iPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:NO];
```

I receive an error:

```
attempt to scroll to invalid index path
```

Comment: Does it print the index path you're trying to reach in the error message? If it does, and it is, let's say, `[section, row]`. Try to `NSLog` `[self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];` and let us know

Comment: Thank you micantox. Printing numberofItemsInSection revealed that the view it used for scrolling was stale. When I used the scrollToItemAtIndexPath after refreshing the view, it worked!

Comment: did you forget to put a dot? i.e "[self.collectionView scroll..." not "[self collectionView scroll..."(please note a dot between self and collectionView)? Looks like the error message states exactly this problem

Comment: @kzia, if this question is resolved don't forget to close it (or provide & approve of an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing numberofItemsInSection revealed that the view it used for scrolling was stale. When I used the scrollToItemAtIndexPath after refreshing the view, it worked!

Answer (score 12):

Do you call `[self.collectionView reloadData];`
before trying to scroll to the indexPath?

If you want to relocate the indexPath when the reloadData finishes, place the code in a block like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0
        animations: ^{ [self.collectionView reloadData]; }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                      NSIndexPath *iPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
                      [self collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:iPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:NO];
 }];
```

Before calling `scrollToItemAtIndexPath`, you could also check the number of items in section to make sure `i` is valid, or you still will get the same error.